# How to separate the data into columns after splitting by ","?

Tags: dolphindb

The code is as below:

```py
def splitColumns(x)
{
 a=split(x,",")
 return a
}
each(splitColumns,t[`bid_prices])
```

An error occurs:

```py
each(splitColumns, t["bid_prices"]) => Not allowed to create a matrix with type STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of "each" is a matrix, the column type of the matrix cannot be a string, you can use the loop function instead:

```py
t=table(1..3 as id,["a,b,c","d,e,f","g,h,i"] as val) 
select id,loop(split{,"," },val) as `col1`col2`col3 from t
```

The value of t is displayed as follows:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | d | g |
| 2 | b | e | h |
| 3 | c | f | i |

If these columns are increased to t, it can be as follows:

```py
t[`col1`col2`col3]=loop(split{,","},t.val)
```

| id | val | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c | a | d | g |
| 2 | d,e,f | b | e | h |
| 3 | g,h,i | c | f | i |